# Should we delete answers that are in context, but not actually addressing the question, more rigorously?

Tags: discussion

This is really just a practical thing.

We get flags like "not an answer" quite often. Actually, we have some of those flags open for some time right now for e.g. [this answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36831/why-is-the-modern-notion-of-motion-inappropriate-to-antiquity/45978#45978) and [this one](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37954/how-would-nietzsche-argue-against-classical-theism/46009#46009).

Obviously, there are cases where, without question, the answer is just bad and should be deleted. In the cases linked, they are eloquent, to some degree sourced. But I, personally, share the sentiment that they are not really answering the question, they only contemplate about related things.

These posts show some insight and may be of value for some users, but the votes do not reflect this hypothetical possibility and users looking for these pieces of information will have trouble to find it via search.

The question is: How should the moderators proceed in cases like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers like these should be deleted, with a comment specifying why. Ideally, it should be made clear that it is not just a personal feeling, but moderation on behalf of community members raising the issue. This can prevent the feeling of being personally disregarded by the moderator team.

If cases like that reoccur for certain members, there should be an offer to discuss the issue in a chat, i.e. how the style of answers could be adjusted and what the problems in particular where.